# Preventing a user from selecting tab items in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, logout

I have an iOS application that uses three different navigation controllers that are embedded within a Tab Bar Controller.  Pretty simple stuff.

How do I block user interface from these tab items?  Is it possible? I want to have a log out button be able to essentially lock out the user from selecting tab items or anything else on the view controller until the log out action is finished.

Added 1/16/14:

If the classes you need to do this in are subclasses of UIViewControllers, you can simply implement the following:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated method in `UITabBarControllerDelegate` for this:

`- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Just return `NO` if you don't want the user to be able to select a given tab bar item.

Comment: I think I found an even better way.  I'll add to my post.  Thanks though.